# Define thresholds based on different categories with RowSum

Tags: r, if-statement, subset, categories, rowsum

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0002", "0005", "0005" ,"0009" ,"0009" ,"0018", "0018" ,"0039" ,"0039" , "0043" ,"0043", "0046", "0046" ,"0048" ,"0048"),
                 Timepoint= c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B",  "A", "B",  "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 sex= c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M","F", "F",  "M", "M",  "M", "M", "F", "F"),
                 country= c("I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S","S", "S",  "I", "I",  "I", "I", "I", "I"),
                 A = c(NA , 977.146 , NA , 964.315 ,NA , 952.311 , NA , 950.797 , 947.465 , 902.852 ,  985.124  ,NA , 930.141 ,1007.790 , 1027.110 , 999.414),
                 B = c(998.988 , NA , 998.680 , NA , 1020.560 ,  955.540 , 911.606 , 964.039   ,  988.087 , 902.367 , 959.338 ,1029.050 , 987.374 ,1066.400  ,957.512 , 917.597),
                 C = c( 987.140 , 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 969.469 , 943.398  ,936.034,  965.292 , 996.404 , 920.610 , 967.047, 913.517 , 893.428 , 921.606 , 929.590  ,950.493), 
                 D = c( 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 1005.820 , 925.752 , 969.469  ,943.398 ,  965.292 , 996.404 ,  967.047 ,  NA , 893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , 929.590 , 950.493),
                 E = c(1006.330, 1028.070 ,  954.274 ,1005.910  ,949.969 , 992.820 ,934.407 , 948.913 ,    961.375  ,955.296 , 961.128  ,998.119 ,1009.110 , 994.891 ,1000.170  ,982.763),
                 G= c(NA , 958.990 , 924.680 , 955.927 , NA , 949.384  ,973.348 , 984.392 , 943.894 , 961.468 , 995.368 , 994.997 ,  979.454 , 952.605 ,NA , 956.507), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have this code to categorize people with 3 or more columns out of range, the threshold would be 1015:

```
cols <- 5:10
df$Myo <- ifelse(rowSums(df[cols] > 1015, na.rm = TRUE) >= 3, 'Yes', 'No')
```

I would need to trick this code into 2 other codes:

- one code that has a different threshold for by sex (theshold of 1004 for female (`df$sex==F`) and 986 by male (`df$sex==M`).
- Other code that selects based on 4 thresholds:

a) first threshold would be males (`df$sex==M`) living in sweden (`df$country==S`), this theshold would be 900

b) second threshold would be females (`df$sex==F`) living in sweden (`df$country==S`), this theshold would be 1016

c) first threshold would be males (`df$sex==M`) living in iceland (`df$country==I`), this theshold would be 800

d) second threshold would be females (`df$sex==F`) living in iceland (`df$country==I`), this theshold would be 1000.

Thanks!!

Comment: What's your desired `Myo` for this `df`? (This will be used to do benckmark to check our answer)

Comment: What's the desired  value (Myo?) if  `a),b),c),d)`  are satisfied respectively?

Comment: Thanks! no, for example in the first output I would be interested in having one threshold for male and another for female. And in the other one (a) b) c) d), females from sweden have one, females from iceland have a different one, and the same for males. I hope this is clear. :) For both outputs, Myo would be yes when 3 of those columns are out range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use `data.table` to solve this. The function `fcase` is used to deal with multi thresholds branch. I am not sure whether the ourputs of `Myo` is your desired or not. Anyway I guess you can correct it and I will edit it later.

```r
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0002", "0005", "0005" ,"0009" ,"0009" ,"0018", "0018" ,"0039" ,"0039" , "0043" ,"0043", "0046", "0046" ,"0048" ,"0048"),
                 Timepoint= c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B",  "A", "B",  "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 sex= c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M","F", "F",  "M", "M",  "M", "M", "F", "F"),
                 country= c("I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S","S", "S",  "I", "I",  "I", "I", "I", "I"),
                 A = c(NA , 977.146 , NA , 964.315 ,NA , 952.311 , NA , 950.797 , 947.465 , 902.852 ,  985.124  ,NA , 930.141 ,1007.790 , 1027.110 , 999.414),
                 B = c(998.988 , NA , 998.680 , NA , 1020.560 ,  955.540 , 911.606 , 964.039   ,  988.087 , 902.367 , 959.338 ,1029.050 , 987.374 ,1066.400  ,957.512 , 917.597),
                 C = c( 987.140 , 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 969.469 , 943.398  ,936.034,  965.292 , 996.404 , 920.610 , 967.047, 913.517 , 893.428 , 921.606 , 929.590  ,950.493), 
                 D = c( 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 1005.820 , 925.752 , 969.469  ,943.398 ,  965.292 , 996.404 ,  967.047 ,  NA , 893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , 929.590 , 950.493),
                 E = c(1006.330, 1028.070 ,  954.274 ,1005.910  ,949.969 , 992.820 ,934.407 , 948.913 ,    961.375  ,955.296 , 961.128  ,998.119 ,1009.110 , 994.891 ,1000.170  ,982.763),
                 G= c(NA , 958.990 , 924.680 , 955.927 , NA , 949.384  ,973.348 , 984.392 , 943.894 , 961.468 , 995.368 , 994.997 ,  979.454 , 952.605 ,NA , 956.507), stringsAsFactors = F)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
cols <- 5:10
df[, Myo := fcase(sex == "F" & rowSums(.SD > 1004,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  sex == "M" & rowSums(.SD > 986,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  default = "No"),
   .SDcols = cols]

df[, Myo2 := fcase(sex == "M" & country == "S" & rowSums(.SD > 900,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  sex == "F" & country == "S" & rowSums(.SD > 1016,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  sex == "M" & country == "I" & rowSums(.SD > 800 ,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  sex == "F" & country == "I" & rowSums(.SD > 1000,na.rm = T) >= 3, "Yes",
                  default = "No"),
   .SDcols = cols]
df
#>     PatientID Timepoint sex country        A        B       C        D        E
#>  1:      0002         A   F       I       NA  998.988 987.140  961.810 1006.330
#>  2:      0002         B   F       I  977.146       NA 961.810  929.466 1028.070
#>  3:      0005         A   M       S       NA  998.680 929.466  978.166  954.274
#>  4:      0005         B   M       S  964.315       NA 978.166 1005.820 1005.910
#>  5:      0009         A   F       S       NA 1020.560 969.469  925.752  949.969
#>  6:      0009         B   F       S  952.311  955.540 943.398  969.469  992.820
#>  7:      0018         A   M       S       NA  911.606 936.034  943.398  934.407
#>  8:      0018         B   M       S  950.797  964.039 965.292  965.292  948.913
#>  9:      0039         A   F       S  947.465  988.087 996.404  996.404  961.375
#> 10:      0039         B   F       S  902.852  902.367 920.610  967.047  955.296
#> 11:      0043         A   M       I  985.124  959.338 967.047       NA  961.128
#> 12:      0043         B   M       I       NA 1029.050 913.517  893.428  998.119
#> 13:      0046         A   M       I  930.141  987.374 893.428  921.606 1009.110
#> 14:      0046         B   M       I 1007.790 1066.400 921.606  976.192  994.891
#> 15:      0048         A   F       I 1027.110  957.512 929.590  929.590 1000.170
#> 16:      0048         B   F       I  999.414  917.597 950.493  950.493  982.763
#>           G Myo Myo2
#>  1:      NA  No   No
#>  2: 958.990  No   No
#>  3: 924.680  No  Yes
#>  4: 955.927  No  Yes
#>  5:      NA  No   No
#>  6: 949.384  No   No
#>  7: 973.348  No  Yes
#>  8: 984.392  No  Yes
#>  9: 943.894  No   No
#> 10: 961.468  No   No
#> 11: 995.368  No  Yes
#> 12: 994.997 Yes  Yes
#> 13: 979.454  No  Yes
#> 14: 952.605 Yes  Yes
#> 15:      NA  No   No
#> 16: 956.507  No   No
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello Peace, thank you so much for your answer. It is not quite but very close! Basically what I need  is a YES when 3 or more variables (5:10) have values that pass the threshold. In the case of the first example, when a female has 3 values in 5:10 that exceed 1004, then it would give me a YES. Is that what this does? - I am unsure, to me comes out as NAs in that column, not YES

Comment: Hi @Lili , I update my answer (code) according to you comment. In the first example, there is no row satisfy  3 values exceed 1004, so it gives a NO for all `sex == "F"`, but 2 rows of `sex == "M"` (row 12, 14 ) have 3 values exceed 986, which gives a `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with this code that also works for the first case:

```
cols <- 5:10
df$sex= as.factor(df$sex)
df %>% mutate(Myo=ifelse(sex == "F" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 1004, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes',
                                      ifelse(sex == "M" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 986, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes','No')))-> df
```

Comment: The function `case_when` (similar to `fcase`) should also work for  this.

Comment: are there benefits of fcase over mutate? (I've realised that mutate can be a bit "moody" - thanks